# How can I know the lock information in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, locking

Is there any tool or way that can get all the information about the locks in java?

for example, if there is a java program, it creates two threads, and both threads require locks for some variable.  Is there any tools that can output the information like which thread locks which variable?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding the cause for deadlock in multi threading?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15936725/finding-the-cause-for-deadlock-in-multi-threading)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ThreadInfo#getLockedSynchronizers() ([JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/management/ThreadInfo.html)) via ThreadMXBean to get array of LockInfo on *currently owned* locks on threads. LockInfo will tell you just class name & identity hashcode of a lock, but that's sufficient in tracing lock objects.

Comment: Thank you! but what I want is getting the thread information of program A by using another program B.  Like program A has two threads, and I want to write another program that could know the threads' information in program A.

Comment: That's exactly what you can do with JMX. See other questions on how to do it; e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/q/5552960/432259