# Java Monitors: Does having a Java monitor with Synchronised Methods Avoid Deadlocks?

Tags: process, resources, synchronization, deadlock, monitor

Basically, if I have lots of synchronised methods in a monitor. Will this effectively avoid deadlocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, no, it does not guarantee the absence of the deadlocks. Please have a look at the code examples at 
[Deadlocks and Synchronized methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260038/deadlocks-and-synchronized-methods%20Deadlocks%20and%20Synchronized%20Methods) and [Deadlock in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217113/deadlock-in-java). The two classes, A and B, with synchronized methods only generate a perfect deadlock.

Also, in my opinion , your wording "Java monitor with Synchronised Methods", although being conceptually correct, slightly deviates from the one accepted in Java. For example the java.lang.Object.wait() javadoc puts in the following way :

"The current thread must own this object's monitor"

That implicitly suggests that the **object** and the **monitor** are not the same thing. Instead, the monitor is something we don't directly see or address.